# How to solve the error "this.props.myFunction" is not a function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app with two components. My child component has a table with some records. Each record has a button and I'm calling a function (editUser) with a parameter (id) in onclick. In that function I'm sending that id to the Parent component through props. The function is already bind in the constructor. But when button click, console says **this.props.userId is not a function**

**Child component :**

```
class UsersTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
        this.editUser = this.editUser.bind(this);

    }

    editUser(id) {
       this.props.userId(id);
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <TableBody>
            {data
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map(n => {
                    return (
                        <TableRow key={n.id}>
                            <TableCell className={classes.fixedTd}>
                                <BorderColorIcon onClick={() => this.editUser(n.userId)} className="action margin-r" />
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    );
                })}
        </TableBody>
        );
    }
}

export UsersTable;
```

**Parent component :**

```
class CompanyUserMgt extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    editUser = (id) => {
        console.log("user", id)
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="">
        <UsersTable
            userId={this.editUser}
                    key={this.state.tableKey}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CompanyUserMgt;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Things look correct to me. My suggestion, try logging `this` and check what it shows. My assumption is that context is being lost somewhere

Comment: everything looks ok. How you're caling `onClick` inside `BorderColorIcon` ?

Comment: Did you make sure that you transpile arrow functions in classes properly? Did you try to declare editUser in regular way?

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı Yes I tried in regular way too. But it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify things, can you plese try below code on your child component?

```
class UsersTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };

    }

    render() {
        return (
        <TableBody>
            {data
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map(n => {
                    return (
                        <TableRow key={n.id}>
                            <TableCell className={classes.fixedTd}>
                                <BorderColorIcon onClick={() => this.props.userId(n.userId)} className="action margin-r" />
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    );
                })}
        </TableBody>
        );
    }
}

export UsersTable;
```

Comment: It worked! Thanx. But still no idea that why the function is not working

Comment: most likely because of this line this.editUser = this.editUser.bind(this); trying to bind an arrow function to an object function